# How to connect the list to get ip address with port?

Tags: python, list

I write python code, and get a list like:

`['221.180.147.30', '86', '61.155.169.11', '808']`

how can i turn it to:

`['221.180.147.30:86', '61.155.169.11:808']`

Comment: `[':'.join(f[0:2]), ':'.join(f[2:4])]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = ['221.180.147.30', '86', '61.155.169.11', '808']
>>> [':'.join(lst[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)]
['221.180.147.30:86', '61.155.169.11:808']
```

Using `zip(*[iter(lst)*N]` trick which introduced in [`itertools` recipe - `grouper`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) (This works for any iterable, not only for list):

```
>>> [':'.join(group) for group in zip(*[iter(lst)]*2)]
['221.180.147.30:86', '61.155.169.11:808']
```

**UPDATE**

Using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> map(':'.join, zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2]))  # In Python 2.x
['221.180.147.30:86', '61.155.169.11:808']
>>> list(map(':'.join, zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2])))  # In Python 3.x
['221.180.147.30:86', '61.155.169.11:808']
```

`zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2])` came from Burhan Khalid's answer.

Comment: I hope this doesn't become a "list all the ways we can do this" kind of post :D

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, I will stop updating answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the `zip(*[iter(lst)]*2)` causes a bit too much headscratching, try the simpler option, that uses the slicing syntax:

```
>>> ['{}:{}'.format(a,b) for a,b in zip(i[::2], i[1::2])]
['221.180.147.30:86', '61.155.169.11:808']
```

How this works is `[::2]` will step over the list skips one item, and `[1::2]` does the same, but skips the first item. In effect, `[::2]` mean "all entries in odd numbered positions" and `[1::2]` is "all entries in even numbered positions":

```
>>> i
['221.180.147.30', '86', '61.155.169.11', '808']
>>> i[::2]
['221.180.147.30', '61.155.169.11']
>>> i[1::2]
['86', '808']
```

`zip` just combines the two to give you the "pairs" as tuples:

```
>>> zip(i[::2], i[1::2])
[('221.180.147.30', '86'), ('61.155.169.11', '808')]
```

Next is up to you to convert these tuples to strings. @falsetru did it with a `':'.join(pair)` and in my example, I am using string formatting. There are a few ways to do this:

```
>>> ['{}:{}'.format(*pair) for pair in zip(i[::2], i[1::2])]
['221.180.147.30:86', '61.155.169.11:808']
>>> [':'.join(pair) for pair in zip(i[::2], i[1::2])]
['221.180.147.30:86', '61.155.169.11:808']
>>> ['{}:{}'.format(ip, port) for ip, port in zip(i[::2], i[1::2])]
['221.180.147.30:86', '61.155.169.11:808']
```

We are both using a *list comprehension* which is an expression that evaluates to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly more succinct...

```
>>> l = ['221.180.147.30', '86', '61.155.169.11', '808']
>>> [':'.join(s) for s in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])]
['221.180.147.30:86', '61.155.169.11:808']
```

Since sockets are tuples of source ip, source port, destination ip, destination port, and protocol, it could also be considered close to what the theoretical type for a socket is.

It looks like a few people came up with the same answer.

Comment: How is this different than my answer?

Comment: It looks like it's essentially the same.  The `format` might be a bit more expensive than the `join` though.

Comment: Succinct is a defect in Python (and most other languages).

Comment: @msw I take it you're not a fan of functional languages?

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> li=['221.180.147.30', '86', '61.155.169.11', '808']
>>> [':'.join(t) for t in zip(li[0::2], li[1::2])]
['221.180.147.30:86', '61.155.169.11:808']
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers.

Comment: It wasn't a duplicate when posted